# Keep suggestions contant for AutoCompleteTextView's setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've an AutoCompleteTextView in which I want to display suggestion from web service when we touch on it like in this [url](http://ubooktoday.com/). Problem is the suggestion shows only as long as I touch it, and it stops showing the suggestion when I remove the touch. I want to show the suggestion even after I've removed touching the AutoCompleteTextView. So any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    AutoCompleteTextView auto;
    private List<String> suggest;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private static final String SPANAME = "My_API_Link";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        suggest = new ArrayList<String>();

        auto = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.auto);
        auto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                prepareSpa();
                auto.showDropDown();
                auto.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareSpa(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SPANAME,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        try {

                            suggest = new ArrayList<String>();

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                                String dataAdd = jsonarray.getString(i);
                                if(!dataAdd.equals(null))
                                    suggest.add(dataAdd);
                            }

                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, suggest);

                            auto.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("location", "Dummy Text");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: try to use TextWatcher

Comment: I can't as the suggestion will be coming even when no text is there in ACTV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the custom AutoCompleteTextView mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/furycomptuers/4961368) and with some trial and error got the desired result.

```css
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    InstantAutoComplete auto;
    private List<String> suggest;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private static final String SPANAME = "My_API_Link";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        suggest = new ArrayList<String>();

        auto = (InstantAutoComplete)findViewById(R.id.auto);
        auto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                prepareSpa();
                auto.showDropDown();

            }
        });


  
    }

    private void prepareSpa(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SPANAME,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        try {

                            suggest = new ArrayList<String>();

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                                String dataAdd = jsonarray.getString(i);
                                if(!dataAdd.equals(null))
                                    suggest.add(dataAdd);
                            }

                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, suggest);

                            auto.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("location", "Dania,Florida,33312");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

```html
public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

        if (getWindowVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            Log.d("InstantAutoComplete", "Window not visible, will not show drop down");
            return;
        }

        if (focused) {
            //performFiltering(getText(), 0);
            showDropDown();
        }
    }
}
```